# Is there a way to export json data to docx, pdf and excel in node or client javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pdf, export

I've been looking for a way to export json data to 3 main formats which is [docx, xlsx and pdf].

so far i've been able to simply do this in node:

```
var data = req.body["exportData"];

var headers = req.body["exportHeaders"];

var delimitedHeaders = "";

headers.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if ((headers.length - 1) != index) {
        delimitedHeaders += item + ',';
    } else {
        delimitedHeaders += item + '\r\n';
    }
});

var excelData = "";

data.forEach(function (item) {
    var keyCount = Object.keys(item).length;

    var lastProp = Object.keys(item)[keyCount - 1];

    for (var prop in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (prop != lastProp) {
                excelData += item[prop] + ',';
            } else {
                excelData += item[prop] + '\r\n';
            }
        }
    }
});

fs.writeFile('file.xls', '\ufeff ' + headers + '\r\n' + excelData, {encoding: 'utf8'}, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.end();
});
```

The problem is that it's too simple and there is no way of adding any design related features also it only works with xls and csv but can't use it for doc and pdf even in xls i want it to appear as data table with headers but i can't specify that.

Please help me :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html.

It supports by default
    PNG
    GIF
    JPEG
    PDF

Comment: Thanks but it's not an acceptable solution, This only captures the html which is not the case :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you build a csv format file with xls extension.
You have to use some external libraries/converters for data export, because  doc xls and pdf are containers. For example, you can use a virtural pdf printer to build pdf document.  Also, you can build rtf file instead of doc, http://www.pindari.com/rtf3.html . 
Good luck.